# Hyperlinks and line-numbering

Tags: hyperref, line-numbering

For the following MWE `hyperref` complains that it can not find a target for the link, and thus does not create a link. What can I do to make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagewiselinenumbers

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
foo\linelabel{l:foo}

\lipsum[3]
Line~\ref{l:foo} on page~\pageref{l:foo}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the code I posted at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129570/15925 help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Hi Andrew, that is quite good! The other question is newer, but has an accepted answer, so I would not want to close it as duplicate. So I'd like to suggest that you give another answer here, maybe even proposing something for the nonworking `\pageref`. Acceptance guaranteed ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work-around I gave in [Hyperref and lineno: always jumping to first page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129541/15925) is easily extended to page references via a new command `\lpageref`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[right]{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\llabel}[1]{\hypertarget{llineno:#1}{\linelabel{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\hyperlink{llineno:#1}{\ref*{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lpageref}[1]{\hyperlink{llineno:#1}{\pageref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\Blindtext
\llabel{test}\Blindtext

Finally, we reference line \lref{test} on page~\lpageref{test}.
\end{document}
```