# Hyperref and lineno: always jumping to first page

Tags: hyperref, line-numbering

I have a document where lines are numbered. I want to reference some special lines, for which the correct line numbers are generated. But using `hyperref` does not give the expected result: clicking on a line reference always moves me to the first page of the document, not the page which the referenced line is on. Check the following minimal example for reproducing my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[right]{lineno}

\begin{document}
  \linenumbers
  \lipsum[1-8]
  \textbf{Here is the line, I want a reference to.}\linelabel{test}
  \lipsum[5-8]
  \textbf{Here is the line, where I refence a the special line (on page two):
  \ref{test}}
\end{document}
```

I'm using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Are you aware of this info    http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2012-July/049369.html

Comment: I get no hyperlink, just the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117883/27635

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up a system for creating such references using `hyperref`s commands `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`.  I have called the labelling command `\llabel` and the reference command `\lref`.  The `llineno:` prefix is to avoid clashes with other target names.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[right]{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\llabel}[1]{\hypertarget{llineno:#1}{\linelabel{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{\hyperlink{llineno:#1}{\ref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \linenumbers
  \lipsum[1-8]
  \llabel{test}\textbf{Here is the line, I want a reference to.}
  \lipsum[5-8]
  \textbf{Here is the line, where I refence a the special line (on
  page two): \lref{test}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The above solution works. It is still a workaround though. But as Jesse mentioned, the problem has already been discussed among the maintainers of the respective packages. The problem cited by karlkoeller is probably of the same nature, so maybe these two questions should be merged?