# external cross-reference to a line number using lineno and xr-hyper

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, line-numbering, xr

I try to reference a line number in `source.tex` from a `dest.tex` document. When (PdfLaTeX-)compiling `dest`, I get the following error.

```
! Extra \else.
\@hyper@readexternallink ...#7\\{#3}{#2}{#7}\else 
                                      \ifx \@pdftempa \@pdftempw...
l.10 ...:mylinelabel}{line \ref*{lin:mylinelabel}}
                                              .
```

Here is `source.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\llabel}[1]{\hypertarget{lintarget:#1}{}\linelabel{lin:#1}}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

The label is \llabel{mylinelabel} here.

Reference to line: \ref*{lin:mylinelabel}.

Reference with ref as argument: \href{file:source.pdf\#lintarget:mylinelabel}{line \ref*{lin:mylinelabel}}.
\end{document}
```

Here is `dest.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{source}
\newcommand{\lref}[1]{}

\begin{document}
Reference to line in source: \href{file:source.pdf\#lintarget:mylinelabel}{line} \ref*{lin:mylinelabel}.

Reference to line in source with ref as argument: \href{file:source.pdf\#lintarget:mylinelabel}{line \ref*{lin:mylinelabel}}.
\end{document}
```

The second reference in `dest.tex` triggers the error. The only difference is that the `ref*` is inside the `href` argument. The error seems to stem from some subtle interaction between `lineno`, `xr-hyper`, `ref*` and `href`: including `ref*` command in an `href` argument normally does not cause problem, as seen in `source.tex` which compiles just fine.

Note that I must use `ref*` instead of `ref`, otherwise when compiling `dest`, I get the following error.

```
Runaway argument?
{\@firstoffive }\fi . \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \Hy@setref@link.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
<*> dest.tex
```

(I got inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129570/22016) post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lineno` does not add a hyperref anchor to the label. This causes `xr-hyper` to assume that hyperref is not used.
This leads to problems, if the hyperref `\ref` command tries to use the label.
Actually this is also triggered for the `\ref*` outside of the `href`: You can see that the period at the end of the line is not printed in the pdf file.

You can fix the `xr-hyper` problem by adding

```
\makeatletter
  \long\def\myempty{}
  \def\XR@addURL#1{\XR@@dURL#1\myempty{}{}{}{}{}\\}
  \def\XR@@dURL#1#2#3#4#5#6#7\\{%
    {#1}{#2}%
    \ifx\myempty#6\@empty
      {#3}{#4}{\XR@URL}%
    \else
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
```

before any `\externaldocument`s in `dest.tex`. This tells `xr-hyper` to always add `hyperref` style references, if the original reference was compatible to hyperref.

Comment: Great! But AFAICS, it messes up \cref, which used to work (not for references to lines, but for references to sections in the external document, for example)

Comment: @OlivierCailloux Fixed it.

Comment: Greater! Can this tweak lead to problems? Should I suggest to the `hyperref` maintainer to modify this in `xr-hyper` (part of the `hyperref` bundle)?

Comment: I currently does not see how this could lead to problems, but I haven't tested it much. This would not have to be changed inside `xr-hyper`, the changed code lies inside `hyperref` itself.